# Filter a listview populated by cursor adapter

Tags: android, filter, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I populated a listview with cursor adapter which contains rows from a database.

I want filter the items of the listview, but when I do with:

```
list.getFilter().filter(String);
```

it doesn't work.

How can I filter the items by cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/CursorFilter.java#CursorFilter), it seems like the `CursorAdapter` expects a *query*, not a plain string, see line 49.

EDIT:

Nevermind, you need to first initialize your query provider with a call to [`setFilterQueryAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#setFilterQueryProvider%28android.widget.FilterQueryProvider%29).